# El visor de informes de SAP Crystal Report no muestra informes migrados de Crystal Report 8.5 a 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

Tengo un Crystal Reports en la versión 8.5, ahora migro o actualizo (la palabra que mejor se ajuste) a la versión de Sap Crystal Reports 2013 de estos informes. Hasta este punto todo está bien.

El problema aparece cuando intento visualizarlos en el Crystal Report Viewer 2016, abre el archivo y aparece este mensaje:

"No hay datos guardados. Este archivo de informe no contiene datos guardados y no se puede ver".

"Para incorporar los datos en el informe, ábralo y guárdelo nuevamente en la aplicación Crystal Reports Designer con la opción" Guardar datos con el informe "seleccionada".

Sigo las instrucciones para "guardar datos con el informe" pero el problema persiste.

Algo diferente sucede cuando el informe se crea como nuevo en la versión 2013, este se abre correctamente.

Pero hay muchos informes que tienen que ser migrados y volverlos a hacer sería tedioso

Comment: Puedes probar cambiando tu método de conexión a la base de datos, ya que el Crystal Reports utiliza mucho persistencia con la conexión, en mi caso utilizo varias conexiones ODBC de igual manera por seguridad el te seguirá pidiendo la contraseña si no utilizas por un periodo de tiempo prolongado el dicho reporte(Esto en Crystal Reports no al usuario final). Actualiza tus conexiones y carga información reciente sobre tu reporte.

Comment: En que menú hago ese cambio?

Comment: En la parte derecha donde se encuentra el Explorador de Campos, click derecho sobre la opción Campos de base de datos luego en la opción **Establecer ubicación del origen de datos** luego saltara una venta desde allí modifica o crea las nuevas conexiones a la base de datos.

Comment: lo he intentado pero me cambia las relaciones entre tablas lo que hace que no me traiga la información correcta, hay alguna manera de editar la consulta sql?

Comment: Editar la consulta desde crystal no tienes que hacerlo desde tu gestor de base de datos.

Comment: En que parte? no veo la opción de editar la consulta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95742/discussion-between-araad1992-and-luis-m-lopez).